# Vue multiselect is not displaying in ASP.NET Core

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, vue-component, vue-multiselect

Here is html code and JS code I have also tried changing package version but vue-multi select is not working:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
import 'vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css';    
Vue.config.performance = true;    
window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            Multiselect
        },
        data: {
            selected: null,
            options: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
        }
    });
```

And my dependencies are

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"vue-js-modal": "^1.3.34",
"vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6"
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">  
    <multiselect v-model="selected": options="options"></multiselect> 
    Selected: {{selected}} 
</div>
```